# When we add two abstract methods in an interface and implement just one method then why can't we implement the other method using lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-interface

I am practising lambda functions, what I know is to work with them we need to create a functional interface, that contains only one unimplemented abstract method.

So I was wondering why does java don't allow more than one abstract method even if they have different signatures. So I read through related questions on Stack Overflow. And this is what I got. [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466315/why-not-multiple-abstract-methods-in-functional-interface-in-java8/45467070)

> The answer would be that in order to create a valid implementation, you would need to be able to pass N lambdas at once and this would introduce a lot of ambiguity and a huge decrease in readability.

Now I did a little experiment, I created an interface with two implemented abstract methods with different signatures.

This is `myInterface` interface

```java
interface MyInterface {
    abstract void func();
    abstract void func(int i);
}
```

And implemented one function as we normally do and the other as a lambda expression

This is `Lambda` class

```java
class Lambda implements MyInterface{

    public void doWork(MyInterface myInterface) {
        myInterface.func();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lambda lambda = new Lambda();
        lambda.doWork( e -> System.out.println("func:" + e ));
    }

    @Override
    public void func() {
        System.out.println("func");
    }
    
}
```

Obviously this code doesn't work. I just can't understand even though I have two different signatures and even if one of them is implemented normally then why can't we implemented the other remaining method with a lambda. Is it something to do with code quality and maintainability? Can anyone explain I can't get my head around it? Pls, give an example if possible.

Comment: Using `public` and `abstract` for methods in an interface is unnecessary, and therefor recommended to avoid. The lambda you pass in your `main` method has no relation the `Lambda` class at all, so your question doesn't make much sense. And in any case, the specification says a functional interface cannot have more than one abstract method. So an interface with two abstract methods cannot be used by specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a sub-interface of `MyInterface` with all but one methods implemented using the `default` keyword. It allows you to provide *default* implementations that interface implementers "inherit" if they do not provide own implementations. Thus methods with default implementation are not abstract anymore. If you default-implement all but one interface in s sub-interface effectively you end up with a functional interface (a single abstract method interface). And this allows you to use lambda expressions.

```
interface PartialInterface extends MyInterface {
    @Override
    default void func() {
        System.out.println("func");
    }
}
```

```
class Lambda {
    public void doWork(PartialInterface myInterface) {
        // both methods from the interface can be used
        myInterface.func();    // the default implementation "inherited" from PartialInterface
        myInterface.func(42);  // the single abstract method (inherited by PartialInterface from myInterface) overridden by the lambda expression
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lambda lambda = new Lambda();
        lambda.doWork(e -> System.out.println("func:" + e));
    }
}
```